# rails server not working after installation of letsencrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lets-encrypt

After installing `letsencrypt` and dependencies, `rails server` stopped working. I have tried reinstalling ruby in rbenv without luck.

```
/Users/luis/Developer/commerceapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/Users/luis/Developer/commerceapp/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/luis/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/luis/Developer/commerceapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try to run `spring stop` and then `bin/spring`

Comment: Or remove spring altogether; it’s buggy and has low utility and frequently breaks leading to issues like this, leading to a lot of lost time.